# Discouraged Class Usage PHPCS

Tags: phpcodesniffer, phpcs

Let's say I have these classes:

- `Old_Class`
- `New_Class`

If this exists `->something(new Old_Class())` or `Old_Class::staticMethod()` or `$oldClass->methodCall()` I want a code sniff to warn "Old_Class usage found, recommend using New_Class instead".

I found this sniff `Generic.PHP.ForbiddenFunctions` but it only seems to catch built-in php functions `is_array, is_null, etc`.

Do I need to write a custom sniff for this?

If so, what `token` should I added to the `register()` function to catch on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't use a built-in one.  I had to write one using T_STRING.

```php
public function register()
{
    return [
        T_STRING,
    ];
}

public function process(PHP_CodeSniffer_File $phpcsFile, $stackPtr)
{
    $tokens = $phpcsFile->getTokens();

    if ($tokens[$stackPtr]['content'] === 'Old_Class') {
        $error = 'Old_Class usage found, consider using New_Class instead.';
        $phpcsFile->addWarning($error, $stackPtr);
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution does not account for the subclasses of `Old_Class`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a fairly old question, but there are two possible solutions I'm aware of:

1. The Slevomat coding standard for Codesniffer includes [a sniff to report usage of any of an array of forbidden classes](https://github.com/slevomat/coding-standard/blob/master/doc/php.md#slevomatcodingstandardphpforbiddenclasses-)
2. Static analysis tools are another approach for this. If you mark a class with the `@deprecated` annotation, I know from personal experience that Psalm will flag it with the [DeprecatedClass](https://psalm.dev/docs/running_psalm/issues/DeprecatedClass/) issue, and if you can't fix them all at once, you can add them to the baseline, which will suppress the issue, but keep track of it, so you can still use Psalm in continuous integration and not break on existing issues. I believe PHPStan has similar functionality.

Comment: There's now another possible solution for this - the [Pest Architecture plugin](https://pestphp.com/docs/arch-testing) allows you to write a test which fails if a specific class is used withing a given namespace.